# Generate substrings from a string in Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl, substring

I have a string of characters which I want to break down in its substrings on the spaces between words, but the number of spaces spanning between a substring should not be more than 4.

E.g.: String: 
*"Baicalein, a specific lipoxygenase (LOX) inhibitor, has anti-inflammatory and antioxidant effects."*
The resulting substrings should look like
1. *Baicalein,*
2. *Baicalein, a*
3. *Baicalein, a specific*
4. *Baicalein, a specific lipoxygenase*
5. *Baicalein, a specific lipoxygenase (LOX)*
6. *a*
7. *a specific*
...
I feel there must be some way with Regex, but I'm not sure

## EDIT

Code that I have used:

```
my @arr = split('\s', $line);
for(my $i=0; $i<$#arr; $i++)
{
my $str1 = $arr[$i];
my $str2 = $arr[$i].' '.$arr[$i+1];
my $str3 = $arr[$i].' '.$arr[$i+1].' '.$arr[$i+2];
my $str4 = $arr[$i].' '.$arr[$i+1].' '.$arr[$i+2].' '.$arr[$i+3];
}
```

I have very long strings and by this approach it takes a lot of time.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why do you think regex would help at all?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an inner loop to avoid the repeated code.  Also, repeatedly gluing stuff with the dot operator is less efficient.

```
my @substrings;
for (my $i=0; $i<=$#arr; ++$i)
{
    for (my $j=0; $j<5 && $i+$j<=$#arr; ++$j)
    {
        push @substrings, join(' ', @arr[$i..$i+$j]);
    }
}
```

You'll notice the additional boundary condition to prevent the inner loop from going past the end of the input array, and the use of a new array `@substrings` to contain the results.  Finally, see how indentation helps you see what goes where.

Comment: The TextCat module in SpamAssassin does something similar.  They use `substr` to pull out substrings, rather than repeatedly joining stuff together, which is probably more efficient.  Also, they *removed* the inner loop for performance reasons, yielding code somewhat more like yours.

Comment: Your answer will further add to the time complexity and I want something which works better in terms of time.

Comment: The code you show has two bugs, which I have corrected, and one efficiency problem, which I have corrected (and of course the indentation is missing, which I also addressed). If you take just those fixes and corrections from my answer, is it slower? In any event, perhaps you should update your question with fixed code so we don't have to discuss those bug fixes (make it right, *then* make it fast). I have not performed timings but perhaps you should -- how much does dot cost over `join`, and maybe against `substr` as suggested but not shown?